# How can I erase a border piece using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a matrix effect using only HTML/CSS, and the way how i found is to apply a solid border and now erase some piece at top and bottom, someone knows how can I create this effect only using CSS (If it's possible) ?

There is a pic to explain better my objective:

[image]

Comment: Do you *actually* intend to use a table? Because it makes @awesome's solution more suited to adress your problem.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A semantic way is to not give the actual element a border at all! You use `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements as transparent boxes on the right and left side. The pseudo elements are given transparent backgrounds and borders that don't overlap the content which creates the effect.

This works with any background: http://jsfiddle.net/kkYrP/8/

```
.box{
    position:relative;
}
.box:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    width: 8%;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    border-right:none;
    z-index:1;
}
.box:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    right: -2px;
    bottom:-2px;
    width: 8%;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    border-left:none;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Note: if you're having clicking/hovering issues try adding `pointer-events:none;` on the `:before` and `:after`.

Comment: Doesn't work (jsfiddle #6) with a background on .box

Comment: What? The background still extends on to the border.

Comment: Hey I'm using FF28  and fiddle #6 and #7 have same outcome with background-color. To me they are both working fine.

Comment: I see what @bjb568 is talking about and I've addressed it. He's really making me work for it!

Comment: Of course, a better answer is always good so I appreciate the eagle eyes. :)

Comment: ok just tested #8 and works fine in Firefox like #6 and #7, so I'm gonna vote you up.

Comment: That's a pretty neat answer. Nice use of before and after.

Comment: For the best answer I'd recommend reproducing the relevant lines of CSS here so readers aren't forced to click on links just to see how it's done in code. Plus, jsFiddle is notorious for perpetual downtimes, which would make this answer barely more than "You can use `:after` and `:before`" full stop for those who can't access it during those spates.

Comment: @BoltClock Agreed, I have added the css to the answer. I've also removed the less-desirable solution I posted as the first part of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/kkYrP/5/

Give a border-left and right:

```
.box {
    border-left:2px solid #333;
    border-right:2px solid #333;
}
```

And add pseudo elements with negative z-index:

```
.box:before{
    content:"";
    background:#333;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    left:-2px;
    width: 20px;
    top:-2px;
    bottom:-2px;
}
.box:after{
    content:"";
    background:#333;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    right:-2px;
    width: 20px;
    top:-2px;
    bottom:-2px;
}
```

This adresses @David's problems and is based on @James's solution.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/awesome/4gB43/1/

using `background-image` and `linear-gradient`:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image#Browser_compatibility
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient#Browser_compatibility

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 90% 100%;
    background-color: black;
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white);
}
.wrapper-inner {
    display: block;
    background: white;
    padding: 5px;
}
table td {
    border-top: none !important;
}
table {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper-inner">
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="sr-only">
                <tr>
                    <th>Whatever</th>
                    <th>Again, Whatever</th>
                    <th>Finally, Whatever</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>71571</td>
                    <td>26157</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>-497461.35798</td>
                    <td>-143674.72856</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>-6391.62859</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Extending James Bruckner's response, I recently had to do something similar, but I had to do it with curly braces. Basically, you add the braces as content in `:after` and `:before` and you position absolute them. You can see the implementation in the link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/kaNG2/

Your HTML

```
<div class="box">This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. </div>
```

Your CSS

```
div {
    padding:3em;
    font-size:1em;
    width:20em;
    position:relative;
}

div:after,
div:before {
    font-size:6.7em;
    color:#999;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}

div:before {
    content: "[";
    left:0;
}

div:after {
    right:0;
    content:"]";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to give a simplest alternative, using a `linear-gradient` on a pseudo-element.
This way doesn't use extra markup, and you won't have any mouse-event issue.

[image]

```css
table.matrix {
    position: relative;
    background: white;
}
table.matrix:before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    left: -2px;
    right: -2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 10%, white 10%, white 90%, black 90%);
}

/* Non-required stuff */
td {
    padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

```html
<table class="matrix">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@TwBootstrap</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/awesome/bA7d3/

CSS:

```
.table.table-custom tr:first-child td:first-child {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}
.table.table-custom tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.table.table-custom tr:first-child td:last-child {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}
.table.table-custom tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
.table.table-custom {
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
}
.table.table-custom td {
    border-top: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could draw the braces in elements next to the one containing the numbers. This will give you the effect you want.

### CSS

```
span.leftBrace
{
width:10px;
height:100px;
float:left;
border-width:5px;
border-top-style:solid;
border-right-style:none;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-left-style:solid;
}
span.rightBrace
{
float:right;
width:10px;
height:100px;
border-width:5px;
border-top-style:solid;
border-right-style:solid;
border-bottom-style:solid;
border-left-style:none;
}
span.Brace
{
height:100px;
display:inline;
width:200px;
}
```

### HTML

```
<span class="Brace">
<span class ="leftBrace"> </span>
<span class =""> TEXT</span>
<span class ="rightBrace"> </span>
</span>
```

Example of working code here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Jyzd/)

Comment: Only for fixed height braces.

Comment: @bjb568 True but the OP didn't mention anything about dynamic sizes.

Comment: This is a reasonable solution, but would be better done using before and after pseudoelements.